# Where is the APK file created when building with Ionic 4 and Capacitor?

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic4, capacitor

I would like to get the APK file so I can install it manually rather than running through android studio.
If I search in the android directory I can see a few and the most likely is:
[project]\android\app\build\intermediates\instant-run-apk\debug\app-debug.apk

However this doesn't install properly on my device.
It works fine if I build and run through Android studio via Ionic using:
ionic capacitor run android

**Do I need to do a signed production build for this to work?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Android Studio menu `Main Menu` -> `Build Bundle(s) / APK(s)` -> `Build APK(s)`. This then pops up a link with which you can open the file location.

Comment: Hi, do we have any way to generate .apk file using command line.

Answer (score 1):

Ionic 4 app apk file location as below

[project]\platforms\android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app_debug.apk

Comment: That is the Cordova path

Answer (score 0):

You have to types of builds and android studio house each build in different location:
1) Debug Build: android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app_debug.apk
2) Release Build: android\app\release\app.aab

Answer (score 0):

We have to types of builds and android studio house each build in a different location:

1) Debug Build:

> `android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app_debug.apk`

2) Release Build:

> `android\app\release\app.aab`

Answer (score 0):

You can find it after finishing your building process it will give you the location in command prompt itself just copy it and paste in the mypc quick access section it will be in top of your my pc screen..
then you will go to your apk directory.

Answer (score 0):

To build from command line (without opening and fussing with Android Studio), just do [`ionic capacitor copy android && cd android && ./gradlew assembleDebug && cd ..`](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-build-an-android-apk-file-without-using-android-studio-in-a-capacitor-project/177814/9)

Then you'll find the APK at the usual place (`/android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug`).